# SQL db2 update query for multiple rows

Tags: sql, database, db2, sql-update

I am updating records by the following queries:

```
update tableA set Quantity=
(select count(*) from table B where ID=x)
where ID=x

update tableA set Quantity=
(select sum(Stock) from table C where ID=y)
where ID=y
```

Example(Corrected):

[image]

All the ID from tableA are divided into 2 tables: TableB and TableC. I have to update the quantity field of TableA with count of TableB ( if ID.TableA is in TableB) and update the quantity field of TableA with sun(stock) of TableC ( if ID.TableA is in TableC)

There are 500k IDs to be updated like this. I was wondering how it can be done without having to execute 500k queries.

EDIT: I am fetching the count of rows from TableB, count is not a column for TableB.

Any help will be appreciated,TIA!

Comment: What if `ID` is not in tableB nor tableC? Use a null, a zero, do not update, other?

Comment: All the ID are in either TableB or in TableC

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update tableA
    set Quantity = (select count(*) from table B where B.ID = A.ID)
```

Comment: "select count from table B where B.ID = A.ID"

This gives my the count of all field where B.ID = A.ID. The count it provides me is 600K. It will update all Quantity = 600k.

Comment: ‘count of TableB’. Count - is this a column of the TableB? Or o you want ‘select count(*) from tableb where ID=x’ instead of your ‘select count from tableb where ID=x’?

Comment: I am sorry if it was not clear, count is not a column. I am fetch the count of rows for B.ID=x

Answer (score 0):

The names of your tables and columns are not 100% clear to me from your question, so I'm guessing a little bit about them. Correct if needed:

```
update tablea a set quantity = case
  when (select count(*) from tableb where b.id = a.id) is not null then
    (select count(*) from tableb b where b.id = a.id)
  else
    (select sum(stock) from tablec c where c.id = a.id)
  end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! "select count(*) from tableB where b.id = a.id" will give me the count of all the records where B.id=A.id. While what I need is updating the count of B.id=1 to quantity.TableA where A.id=1 and count of B.id=2 to quantity.TableA where A.id=2 and so on.

Comment: Please some example data for tableA, TableB, and TableC, and the expected result. A few rows will go a long way.

Comment: Updated image in original post.

Comment: `select count(*) from tableB where b.id = a.id` will count only the rows matching the id. For example, for ID=1 it will find three rows and produce the value `3`. Is this what you want? For ID=2 it will find two rows and produce the value `2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare global temporary table tablea(id int not null, quantity int) with replace on commit preserve rows not logged;
declare global temporary table tableb(id int not null) with replace on commit preserve rows not logged;
declare global temporary table tablec(id int not null, stock int) with replace on commit preserve rows not logged;

insert into session.tablea values (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0);
insert into session.tableb values 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3;
insert into session.tablec values (4, 3), (5, 2), (5, 2), (5, 1), (6, 3), (6, 4);

update session.tableA a 
set Quantity=coalesce(
  nullif((select count(*)   from session.tableb b where b.ID=a.ID), 0)
, (select sum(stock) from session.tablec c where c.ID=a.ID)
);

select * from session.tableA;
```

Comment: "select count(*) from tableB b where b.ID=a.ID" gives me the sum of all the count (*) from TableB where A.ID exists. I need to update the respective count of all A.id to be updated in TableA  when A.id exists in B. 

If you look at my image uploaded in the original post, your solution will update quantity of 1,2 and 3 as 6 whereas i need quantity of 1,2, and 3 to be as 3,2 and 1 respectively.

Comment: Run the amended example as is and compare the result with your image.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort, but this is in production. I do not have the access and authorisation to create a new table/column.

Comment: Try this on you test then. This was just to show that the update statement works as you need - you get the same results as you provided in the picture. BTW, I used global temporary tables only. So, no persistent tables are created here.